# cgi / variables from website form

Tags: html, c, web, cgi

Someone know what is wrong in following code?

```
printf("%s%c%c\n","Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);
printf("<TITLE>VASTAUS</TITLE>\n");
printf("<H3>The Result is!!!</H3>\n");

data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
sscanf(data, "v=%lf&energiaLuokka=%c[^&]&kaupunki=%s[^&]&vuosi=%s[^&]&kuukausi=%s[^&]&pva=%s", &v, &energiaLuokka, kaupunki, vuosi, kuukausi, pva);
printf("Kuutio: %lf luokka: %c kaupunki: %s vuosi: %s kuukausi: %s paiva: %s", v, energiaLuokka, kaupunki, vuosi, kuukausi, pva);
```

It is supposed to pick-up variables given via website form with cgi, but currently it only picks just 2 first value.. resulting output: `Kuutio: 54.000000 luokka: D kaupunki: vuosi: kuukausi: paiva:`

as you can see leaving "kaupunki, vuosi, kuukausi and paiva" variables totally empty.

I also wondered if code is right but problem is in html.. but atleast havent found anything to solve it

```
<BR>
<fieldset><legend>Rakennuksen paikkakunta</legend>
<label class="labelcenter" for="kaupunki">Paikkakunta</label> 
<select name="kaupunki" id="kaupunki"> 
<option value="0">Valitse</option> 
<option value="Espoo">Espoo</option> 
<option value="Forssa">Forssa</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<BR>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think you have missed the `&` on those variables in the `sscanf()`.

Comment: Result remains same.. and those missing values are strings so they shouldn't even need it :/

Comment: Try using CGI module http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html

Answer (score 0):

All of the `[^&]` in your format string probably shouldn't be there.  They are unnatural and superfluous, and they are causing the parsing to fail.

However, I have to ask, why are you using `sscanf()` to parse the query string at all?  It will break if the query string parameters appear in any different order (and there is nothing in any specification that says that browsers must preserve the order of parameters in a form).  Furthermore, you won't be decoding the percent-encoding.

My recommendation is to use a CGI library that does the job properly.

Comment: Hey, Thats why I'm almost totally new (beginner) in programming and I have ever even heard about CGI library eventhought didnt even try to find it because this sscanf() was in exsample code our school teachers gave us when we started to do this project.. but thanks for mentioning it.. maybe I will give it a look. :)